# Google map not displaying

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have a google map that used to work here:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/birds.php

Now I see .js error messages for 
1) initialize not defined ....but I defined it!! Not sure why that appears.
2) Illigal token on line 104 which happens to be a blank line lol

Any ideas what the real problem is on that page that is breaking things?

Thank you?
Alex

Comment: Firebug! Set a breakpoints right before the error. Inspect variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is on line 104 of the html output.

```
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: myLatlng,
              map: map ,
 104 --->     title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + "
                    Date: " + date
              });
```

I found this by looking at the console output in chrome dev tools. It was the first error reported. Firebug for Firefox or any other dev tool would tell you this too.

I'd move the `Date: " + date` up to the end of the previous line. The interpreter probably doesn't like the real newline embedded in a quote.